# Unity IOC with winforms MVP multiple instances

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, unity-container

What i am trying to do is launch a form multiple times inside the main form
i have a 1 to 1 relationship between the view and presenter.
so when either the presnter or view is disposed both of them are release from memory

I just do not know how to achieve this.

I am able to launch the tags form sucessfully once, but on my button click i'd like to launch more tags forms.

```
   [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        var unityContainer = new UnityContainer();
        unityContainer.RegisterType<IMainViewUC, MainViewUC>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
        unityContainer.RegisterType<IMainPresenter, MainPresenter>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
        unityContainer.RegisterType<ITagsPresenter, TagsPresenter>(new PerResolveLifetimeManager());
        unityContainer.RegisterType<ITagsViewUC, TagsViewUC>(new PerResolveLifetimeManager());
        IMainPresenter mainPresenter = unityContainer.Resolve<MainPresenter>();
        IMainViewUC mainView = mainPresenter.GetView();
        Application.Run((MainViewUC)mainView);
    }


public class MainPresenter :IMainPresenter
{
    private IMainViewUC _view = null;
    private ITagsPresenter _tagsPresenter = null;
    public MainPresenter(IMainViewUC view, ITagsPresenter tagsPresenter)
    {
        _view = view;
        _tagsPresenter = tagsPresenter;
        _view.TagsViewEventRaised = ((IMainPresenter)this).OnTagsView;
    }


    void IMainPresenter.OnTagsView()
    {
        var view = _tagsPresenter.GetView();
        _view.AddMdiChildView(view);
    }

    void IMainPresenter.AddChildView(IView view)
    {
        _view.AddMdiChildView(view);
    }

    IMainViewUC IMainPresenter.GetView()
    {
        return _view;
    }
}

public partial class MainViewUC : Form, IMainViewUC
{
  
    Action IMainViewUC.TagsViewEventRaised { get; set; }

    public MainViewUC()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    void IMainViewUC.AddMdiChildView(IView view)
    {
        var form = (Form)view;
        form.MdiParent = this;
        form.Show();
    }

    private void toolStripMenuItem_tags_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ((IMainViewUC)this).TagsViewEventRaised();
    }
  
}
```

Comment: I don't think the unity3d tag applies here, do you mean unity (the framework, unity3d is the game engine)

Comment: thanks, i put in unity and it auto ressolved to unity3d